# Who was the French king during Pope Alexander VI (Borgia)

Tags: pope

Who was the French king during Pope Alexander VI (Borgia)

(watching Borgias TV Show) and interested.

The one who started Italian wars.

Comment: Actually, I voted to close as a "general reference" question, (not really because it is "localized") but because it is too basic and easily answered with a single link. But that option is not available on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the cast listing on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1582457/), it's Charles VIII which makes sense as he started the Italian Wars. He was the last king of France to be a full Valois. The actor who plays him is a good 20 years older than Charles VIII would have been at the time.

Comment: I don't care to look this up myself at the moment, but it seems like there ought to be more reliable sources out there to reference than a cast listing on IMDB...

Comment: He was the French king during this time period. It's definitely him.

Comment: Trying to not cite Wikipedia. The Show's site is of limited value in matters like these though on of the trailers lists King Charles.

Comment: @Sid - Was he the *only* one?

Comment: No, he was not. He died halfway through Alexander's reign. Louis XII reigned until 1515 so that would cover it for all of Alexander's reign.

Comment: Well, as World Engineer said, he was the one who started the Italian Wars so it fits.

Comment: question has been answered and I thank WE. and a little bit ashamed as i I wasnt clever enough to see the cast. LOL. I just updated the title to stop this flame.